Occupied Network Transofrm in Fusion2 Unity
I want to do something like this
[Serializable]
public struct OccupiedTransform
{
    public Transform Transform;
    public PlayerRef Occupier;
}

[SerializeField] private NetworkLinkedList<OccupiedTransform> _occupiedTransformList = new NetworkLinkedList<OccupiedTransform>();

This component should be referenced over the network
you should be able to

See if another PlayerRef occupies this Transform in the network
Assign a player to the OccupiedTransform
Remove player

I was adding this because of my research based on this. However, this does not work, probably because of the data types in the structs. Do you have any idea how to solve that?
https://doc.photonengine.com/fusion/current/manual/fusion-types/network-collections


However, this does not work, probably because of the data types in the structs

This is correct. You can't network arbitrary Unity components (such as Transform), and you can only network structs that inherit from INetworkStruct.
A workaround for this limitation would be to store the NetworkId of a NetworkObject (you can't store NetworkObjects directly inside of a INetworkStruct), and use that to resolve the Transform using Runner.FindObject(id):
public class YourClass : NetworkBehaviour

    public struct OccupiedTransform : INetworkStruct
    {
        public NetworkId ObjectId;
        public PlayerRef Occupier;

        public Transform GetTransform(NetworkRunner runner) {
            // May throw NRE, make sure to handle that...
            return runner.FindObject(ObjectId).transform;
        }
    }

    [Networked, Capacity(#)] private NetworkLinkedList<OccupiedTransform> _occupiedTransformList => default;

    ....
}

